# No "Is initial view controller" in Xcode 6.2

Tags: xcode, viewcontroller

Xcode 6.2 doesn't have the "Is initial view controller" option.

Xcode 6.1

[image]

Xcode 6.2

[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's interesting - I had never actually used that "Is Initial View Controller" checkbox before. I've always just dragged the little arrow around the storyboard if I needed to change the initial VC. Looks like that's Apple's preferred way of setting that option going forward.

[image: Little arrow guy]

Comment: I think you can drag a new arrow out of the object library if you delete the existing one as well

Answer (score 8):

In Xcode 6.2, the "Is initial view controller" box has turned into a "Storyboard Entry Point" object. It can be found in the object library.

[image]

Comment: This object is gone from the object library in Xcode 6.2. You have to tick the `Is Initial View Controller` checkbox in the Attributes Inspector.

Answer (score 0):

Before xcode 6.2, that isintialViewcontroller check mark is there. But no longer in xcode 6.2, drag the entry point from viewcontroller to required viewcontroller